# Does npm update check failed mean npm didn't install?

Tags: npm, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to install npm and when I do, it says:

```
npm update check failed  
Try running with sudo or get access to the local update config store via  
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/username/.config
```

Does this mean that npm did not install? Or did it?

Comment: Try to do `npm -v`if it show a version number then it's installed

Comment: It has been installed.